# mysqli_fetch_row doesn't return results, but mysqli_fetch_assoc does

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm writing a simple php page for an assignment, and one of the criteria is to use both mysqli_fetch_assoc and mysqli_fetch_row.  I'm using the same query for both:

```
<?php
    // Perform database query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM player JOIN stat ON player.playerId = stat.playerId";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbconnection, $query);
    if (!$result) { 
        die("Database query failed");
    }
?>
```

When I run this query in my database, it returns 3 rows as expected.  In my webpage, I use mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) first, and it renders an unordered list with the information as expected.  I then proceed to use mysqli_fetch_row($result) to display more information, but the second while loop doesn't yield any table data (just the content of the th tags).

```
    <h1>The Players</h1>
    <ul>
        <?php
            // Use return data with mysqli_fetch_assoc
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                // output data from each row
        ?>
            <li><?php echo $row["playerId"]; ?></li>
            <li><?php echo $row["fname"] . " " . $row["lname"]; ?></li>
            <li><?php echo $row["team"]; ?></li>
            <li><?php echo $row["position"]; ?></li>
        <?php echo "<hr />";
            }
        ?>
    </ul>

    <h1>The Stats</h1>
    <table>
        <th>Player</th>
        <th>Batting Avg</th>
        <th>Homeruns</th>
        <th>RBIs</th>

// DATA BELOW THIS POINT IS NOT RENDERED BY THE WEBPAGE

        <?php 
            // Use return data with mysqli_fetch_row
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row[2]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[8]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[9]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[10]; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </table>


    <?php
        // Release returned data
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    ?>
```

I'm going to be writing a lot of php for this class in the coming weeks, so I'd really like some tips on how to troubleshoot these kinds of errors myself.  Are there methods I can use to easily check the content of $result to see if any resources were actually passed through?  It appears to me that $row in the second loop isn't getting assigned to anything, so it just doesn't execute the echo commands.

Comment: I suspect that you've already moved your pointer to the end of your results. Try reversing your WHILE statements and see what happens.

Comment: most likely, rows have already exhausted on the assoc loop

Comment: @Shwheelz you could try that or run your query twice.

Comment: Each time the WHILE runs it moved to the next record, so by the time you get to the second WHILE the pointer is already at the end of $result.

Comment: Got it, I just had to make a separate result variable.  Thanks @BigScar.  Could you explain why I can't run it on the same $result variable twice though?  I was under the impression that it was just a list of database resources, and I don't see where it was modified.

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to reset the pointer to the first record before you start the second WHILE, but I don't know what it is, Try googling it.

Comment: @Shwheelz Both functions return the next row in the result set, just in a different format. If you've reached the end of the result set, there's no next row to return.

Comment: @Shwheelz i think `->data_seek()` resets the pointer, try that one out

Comment: There's no separate result set for each fetching function, they both operate on the same result set pointer.

Comment: @Ghost Yes, [`->data_seek()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php) or `mysqli_data_seek()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Adding `<?php $result->data_seek(0) ?>` in between the two fixed it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ghost is correct. When you iterate over the records at the end it doesnt re-set by itselt and it's not a circular list. Because of that you have to manually set it to 0 with $obj->data_seek(int, ie 0); or in procedural style mysqli_data_seek($result,0);